# IAB startSetup NullPointerException

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I am attempting to setup In-App Billing in my application. I haven't got very far and am running into a null pointer exception when trying to start my IabHelper. I am following [this google tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/preparing-iab-app.html#Connect).

```
import com.iabtest.util.IabHelper;
import com.iabtest.util.IabResult;

public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    IabHelper mHelper;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String base64EncodedPublicKey = "My_secret_key";

        mHelper = new IabHelper(this, base64EncodedPublicKey);
        mHelper.enableDebugLogging(true); //Turned on to try to help solve the issue
        Log.d("TEST", "Starting setup.");
        mHelper.startSetup(new IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener()
        {
            public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result)
            {
                Log.d("TEST", "Setup finished.");

                if(!result.isSuccess())
                {
                    // Oh noes, there was a problem.
                    Log.d("TEST", "Problem setting up in-app billing: " + result);
                    return;
                }

                //IAB SET UP!
                Log.d("TEST", "IAB ready");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

In the below logcat, it appears that the null pointer exception is being triggered in IabHelper.java on line 267. Since this is google code, I'm not sure how to fix this. Here is line 267.

```
if (!mContext.getPackageManager().queryIntentServices(serviceIntent, 0).isEmpty()) {
```

Here is my LogCat with the error:

```
12-17 05:28:29.908: E/Trace(1478): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)

12-17 05:28:30.898: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1478): Google Play Store is missing.

12-17 05:28:31.838: D/TEST(1478): Starting setup.

12-17 05:28:31.838: D/IabHelper(1478): Starting in-app billing setup.

12-17 05:28:31.848: D/AndroidRuntime(1478): Shutting down VM

12-17 05:28:31.848: W/dalvikvm(1478): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)

12-17 05:28:31.878: E/AndroidRuntime(1478): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

12-17 05:28:31.878: E/AndroidRuntime(1478): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.iabtest/com.iabtest.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException

12-17 05:28:31.878: E/AndroidRuntime(1478):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)

12-17 05:28:31.878: E/AndroidRuntime(1478):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)

12-17 05:28:31.878: E/AndroidRuntime(1478):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)

12-17 05:28:31.878: E/AndroidRuntime(1478):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)

12-17 05:28:31.878: E/AndroidRuntime(1478):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

12-17 05:28:31.878: E/AndroidRuntime(1478):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)

12-17 05:28:31.878: E/AndroidRuntime(1478):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)

12-17 05:28:31.878: E/AndroidRuntime(1478):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

12-17 05:28:31.878: E/AndroidRuntime(1478):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)

12-17 05:28:31.878: E/AndroidRuntime(1478):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)

12-17 05:28:31.878: E/AndroidRuntime(1478):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)

12-17 05:28:31.878: E/AndroidRuntime(1478):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

12-17 05:28:31.878: E/AndroidRuntime(1478): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

12-17 05:28:31.878: E/AndroidRuntime(1478):     at com.iabtest.util.IabHelper.startSetup(IabHelper.java:267)

12-17 05:28:31.878: E/AndroidRuntime(1478):     at com.iabtest.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:112)

12-17 05:28:31.878: E/AndroidRuntime(1478):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)

12-17 05:28:31.878: E/AndroidRuntime(1478):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)

12-17 05:28:31.878: E/AndroidRuntime(1478):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)

12-17 05:28:31.878: E/AndroidRuntime(1478):     ... 11 more
```

---

Edit: I'm still not sure the reason for the error. However, I have found a useful tutorial that has been better than the google documentation. http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Integrating_Google_Play_In-app_Billing_into_an_Android_Application_%E2%80%93_A_Tutorial

Comment: Have you added the `onActivityResult` in your class ?

Comment: I have not. I am following the tutorial I linked to above, and it did not include on ActivityResult.

Comment: What is com.iabtest.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:112)?

Comment: Line 112 is mHelper.startSetup(new IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener()
I have a few other things in the onCreate method with I removed for ease of reading

Comment: Have you added the google play library in your project ? Please add your full code so that one can understand the issue.

Comment: GrlsHu, yes. I have imported google-play-services_lib and my project uses the library.

Comment: Have you Copied the `IInAppBillingService.aidl` file into your `/src`directory of your Android project.

Comment: IInappBillingService.aidl is in /src/com.android.vending.billing in my project.

Comment: GrlsHu, also I commented out all other code in my onCreate. So the code I posted is all that is running.

Answer (score 67):

Another fine example of Googles 'write once, let others fix our problems'. Even at this moment (June 2014) the 'patch' is still not in the released sdk. To solve the problem replace

```
 if (!mContext.getPackageManager().queryIntentServices(serviceIntent, 0).isEmpty()) {
```

with

```
  PackageManager pm=mContext.getPackageManager();
  List<ResolveInfo> intentServices = pm.queryIntentServices(serviceIntent, 0);
  if (intentServices != null && !intentServices.isEmpty())
```

Then in the dispose code

replace

```
  if (mContext != null) mContext.unbindService(mServiceConn);
```

with

```
  if (mContext != null && mService!=null) mContext.unbindService(mServiceConn);
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Also you should "try .. catch" surround unbindService like this: if (mContext != null && mServiceConn != null) { try {mContext.unbindService(mServiceConn);} catch (Exception e) {logDebug(e.getMessage().toString());} because unbindService may throw exception like "Service not registered".  This could happen when Google Billing Services is not installed on device. And this exception 100% throwed on emulator.

Comment: @a4vi2r, it is indeed true that a 'Service not registered' exception can be thrown. Yet, just swallowing that exception is not a good idea. Better is to start the standard process to install the Google play services (see documentation). I think that was actually demonstrated in source code of the tutorial.

Comment: @Werner Van Belle, unfortunately I did not found this in the tutorial <sdk>/extras/google/play_billing/

Comment: Thank you so much. There're so many crash about this in my app, and I hope this would work.

Comment: Although the code worked on my test phone, on checking google analytics, i got 539 crashes for 'NullPointerException (@IabHelper:startSetup:266) {main}'. No wonder so few people have been able to run my game app. I had just downloaded the game services folder for fresh files too, surprising they still haven't fixed this bug.

Comment: Yeah, that admob code is truly a disaster. One wonders then; how good can they actually count when it comes to impressions and clicks ?

Answer (score 0):

please add jar file of google play services.this is error regrarding missing google play service

Comment: I already have google-play-services_lib imported and my project is using the library (setup in properties > Android > Library). I there something else I need to do to initialize google play services?

Comment: what is line for com.iabtest.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:112)

Comment: Line 112 is mHelper.startSetup(new IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() I have a few other things in the onCreate method with I removed for ease of reading

Answer (score 0):

Probably this issue relates to the issue raised [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=42338)

The updated code hasn't been pushed out to the SDK Manager yet, but you can view all the changes related to this issue here:

https://code.google.com/p/marketbilling/source/detail?r=7ec85a9b619fc5f85023bc8125e7e6b1ab4dd69f

There are 4 files affected by the issue. Make the changes they suggest and see if you still run into the same issue.

Comment: It appears that the changes to the 4 files have been pushed. My files match the diffs.

Comment: That is the whole code. I commented out the rest of the code so the only thing running is the code I posted above. I cleaned out the comments so it was easier to read.

Comment: As i told you in my answer it may be because of some of the files are updated and your files are old. Try out with updated library.

Comment: The library you linked to has since been pushed. I have the updated files.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, it is here that is returning null.

```
Intent serviceIntent = getExplicitIapIntent();
```

Treat this situation:

```
 Intent serviceIntent = getExplicitIapIntent();

        if(serviceIntent != null) {

            if (!mContext.getPackageManager().queryIntentServices(serviceIntent, 0).isEmpty()) {
                // service available to handle that Intent
                mContext.bindService(serviceIntent, mServiceConn, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
            }
        }
```