# IabHelper.startSetup() causes NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, in-app-billing

My app uses In App Billing and it works fine on my phone (`Android 2.3.6`). But when I run it on the emulator (`Android 4.4.2`) it keeps crashing when creating the helper for performing in app purchases. It throws a `NullPointerException`:

```
mHelper = new IabHelper(MainActivity.this, base64EncodedPublicKey);
mHelper.startSetup(new IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {
    public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result) {
        if (!result.isSuccess()) {
            Log.d("x", "In-app Billing setup failed: " + result);
        } 
        else {             
            Log.d("x", "In-app Billing is set up OK");
        }                             
    }
});
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15489975/1352169) says I should put the code above in a try-block and put the catch in the answer below it. I get an error when doing that and the recommended solution is putting that in a try-catch block too. Eventhough I did that, it still crashes.

Can anybody tell me how to do this? I'm completely stuck.

Stack trace:

```
12-24 10:59:51.908: E/AndroidRuntime(2273): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-24 10:59:51.908: E/AndroidRuntime(2273): Process: com.sandradiependaal.mediatie, PID: 2273
12-24 10:59:51.908: E/AndroidRuntime(2273): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-24 10:59:51.908: E/AndroidRuntime(2273):     at com.sandradiependaal.meditatie.util.IabHelper.startSetup(IabHelper.java:267)
12-24 10:59:51.908: E/AndroidRuntime(2273):     at com.sandradiependaal.meditatie.MainActivity$4.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:142)
12-24 10:59:51.908: E/AndroidRuntime(2273):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:299)
12-24 10:59:51.908: E/AndroidRuntime(2273):     at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1113)
12-24 10:59:51.908: E/AndroidRuntime(2273):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2904)
12-24 10:59:51.908: E/AndroidRuntime(2273):     at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3638)
12-24 10:59:51.908: E/AndroidRuntime(2273):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
12-24 10:59:51.908: E/AndroidRuntime(2273):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
12-24 10:59:51.908: E/AndroidRuntime(2273):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
12-24 10:59:51.908: E/AndroidRuntime(2273):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
12-24 10:59:51.908: E/AndroidRuntime(2273):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-24 10:59:51.908: E/AndroidRuntime(2273):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
12-24 10:59:51.908: E/AndroidRuntime(2273):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
12-24 10:59:51.908: E/AndroidRuntime(2273):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
12-24 10:59:51.908: E/AndroidRuntime(2273):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

IabHelper.java:

```
 Intent serviceIntent = new Intent("com.android.vending.billing.InAppBillingService.BIND");
 serviceIntent.setPackage("com.android.vending");
 if (!mContext.getPackageManager().queryIntentServices(serviceIntent, 0).isEmpty()) {
     // service available to handle that Intent
     mContext.bindService(serviceIntent, mServiceConn, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
 }
```

Comment: Which line is "MainActivity$4.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:142)" ?

Comment: Also what is line  267 `IabHelper` class

Comment: @yahya That's the `startSetup()`.

Comment: @Raghunandan I just added it.

Comment: @yoeriboven is `mContext` initialized??

Comment: You DO have com.android.vending.billing package in your application phsyically, right? with IInAppBillingService.aidl and Utils folder...

Comment: Then i assume that your activity's getApplicationContext returns null somehow, you can check source code of IABHelper if you like: https://code.google.com/r/studiozanandroid-appbilling/source/browse/v3/src/com/example/android/trivialdrivesample/util/IabHelper.java?r=7ec85a9b619fc5f85023bc8125e7e6b1ab4dd69f

Answer (score 51):

It's because the list returned is not just empty but it's actually `null`. You can add a simple check if the list is `null`. Why the implementation doesn't return empty list instead of `null` is beyond my comprehension but it's just how it's built.

Change to this:

```
List<ResolveInfo> queryIntentServices = mContext.getPackageManager().queryIntentServices(serviceIntent, 0);
if (queryIntentServices != null && !queryIntentServices.isEmpty()) {
        // service available to handle that Intent
        mContext.bindService(serviceIntent, mServiceConn, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
}
```

This at least did the trick for me with the emulator. This is not needed in real device if implemented correctly.

Comment: If you look at [the documentation for queryIntentServices()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#queryIntentServices(android.content.Intent, int)), it is supposed to return an empty list.  I guess it doesn't follow the contract.

Comment: a great answer was posted on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20626870/iab-startsetup-nullpointerexception

Comment: Although the code worked on my test phone, on checking google analytics, i got 539 crashes for 'NullPointerException (@IabHelper:startSetup:266) {main}'. No wonder so few people have been able to run my game app. I had just downloaded the game services folder for fresh files too, surprising they still haven't fixed this bug.

Answer (score 8):

This seems to be an old thread. Hope this answer helps someone who faces the issue later.
 BI am facing the same issue at this moment.

`IAB` helper generates `NPE` in `startSetup()` only on emulator. But this happens only on AVDs created with Android x.x.x as target.

Try creating your AVD with Google API as target. `IAB` helper does not crash there but you still cannot test the actual billing features.

Comment: What is "ADV" short for?

Comment: Android virtual device. Its AVD.

Answer (score 4):

To test In-app Billing in an application you must install the application on an Android-powered device. **You cannot use** the Android **emulator** to test In-app Billing.

http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html