# Bazaar(Iranian Android Market) inAppBilling error in Android 5 Lollipop

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, android-5.0-lollipop, in-app-billing

For `inAppBilling` in my app use Bazaar(Iranian Android Market) API.

All things are right but in in Android 5 Lollipop this not work correctly and return error :

[image]

After many search found [this similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24480069/google-in-app-billing-illegalargumentexception-service-intent-must-be-explicit) and [this link](http://answers.opencv.org/question/54450/error-opencv4android-caused-by-javalangillegalargumentexception-service-intent-must-be-explicit/) too [this one](https://github.com/onepf/OpenIAB/issues/415).(`solutions are similar together`)

So I try to adding this line :

```
  serviceIntent.setPackage("ir.cafebazaar.pardakht");
```

After this line:

```
  Intent serviceIntent = new Intent("ir.cafebazaar.pardakht.InAppBillingService.BIND");
```

Now app return this Errors :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'boolean java.util.List.isEmpty()' on a null object reference
        at farahang.tedAmouz.BzrBl.util.IabHelper.Setuping(IabHelper.java:227)
        at farahang.tedAmouz.adapters.slideMenuAdapter.onClick(slideMenuAdapter.java:155)
```

---

Codes work completely-correctly in under `Android 5 Lollipop` versions just have problem with `Android 5 Lollipop`!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For binding play services we do something like this:

```
Intent i = new Intent("com.android.vending.billing.InAppBillingService.BIND");
i.setPackage("com.android.vending");
mContext.bindService(e, this.serviceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

Maybe there is something wrong with your `setPackage` replace it with

```
i.setPackage("com.farsitel.bazaar");
```

Instead of

```
i.setPackage("ir.cafebazaar.pardakht");
```